# mongodb write concern

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

As far as I can judge when I set for write "safe" = true, it sets options w = 1, j = 0, it confirms getting of write operation, but doesn't confirm writing to disk (durability). Something like this:

```
$collection->remove(array('_id' => array('$in' => $idsToDelete)), array('safe' => true));
```

Can I set w = 1, j = 1 to guarantee durability (not in the newest driver)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The PHP driver gives you access to the individual [write concern](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.writeconcerns.php) options.

For your case it would be:

```
$collection->remove(
    array('_id' => array('$in' => $idsToDelete)), 
    array("w" => 1, "j" => true));
```